# Remove specific words from csv line that contain specific word

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have meta keywords exported in a csv file

Ex:

```
For Rent ABC-1234 , For Rent ABC-1234 Rental, For Rent ABC1234 , For Rent ABC1234 Rental, For Rent ABC 1234 , For Rent ABC 1234 Rental, For Lease ABC-1234 , For Lease ABC-1234 Rental, For Lease ABC1234 , For Lease ABC1234 Rental, For Lease ABC 1234 , For Lease ABC 1234 Rental
```

What I would like to do is for the values that read "For Rent XXX Rental" to remove the "For Rent" from those values, so that The remaining value would just read "XXX Rental".

Is that possible to do with regex?

Comment: What tool are you using; in other words which Regex implementation?

Comment: Well, I was playing around in Notepad++ just trying to figure it out. I see you can use VB in excel though to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in *Find what* field:

```
For Rent ([^,]+ Rental)
```

Replace with

```
$1
```

`[^,]` means "any character but a comma, `+` - 1 or more times. I see the values are comma-separated, so this seems a safe pattern. For even safer matching, you can try `For Rent ([^,]*? +Rental)` in the *Find what* field (this will also account for multiple spaces before `Rental`).

Output:

```
For Rent ABC-1234 , ABC-1234 Rental, For Rent ABC1234 , ABC1234 Rental, For Rent ABC 1234 , ABC 1234 Rental, For Lease ABC-1234 , For Lease ABC-1234 Rental, For Lease ABC1234 , For Lease ABC1234 Rental, For Lease ABC 1234 , For Lease ABC 1234 Rental
```

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect, I left work for the day, will test it out tomorrow and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
(A[^,]+\d Rental)
```

This will pick out "xxx Rental" from "For Rent/Lease xxx Rental", and you don't need to replace anything.

EDIT:

The above works if the `i` (case-insensitive) flag is not on.

For case insensitive regex, use the following instead:

```
(?<=\w{4}\s|\w{5}\s)([^,]+\d Rental)
```

- `(?<=\w{4}\s|\w{5}\s)` is a **positive look behind** pattern that matches strings followed by `\w{4}\s` (Rent) or `\w{5}\s` (Lease).

---

```
For \w+ \K([^,]+\d Rental)
```

- `\K` discards all previous matches and starts matching from current position.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It changes the line:

"For Lease xxx Rental," to "For Le,"

Comment: Did you have the case-insensitive flag `i`? If so my solution will be problematic, try `(?<=\w{4}\s|\w{5}\s)([^,]+\d Rental)` instead.